# Linked list only prints last word of text file line

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a program that takes in a text file as input and outputs the number of times each word occurs. To do this, I'm using a linked list but whenever I print the list, only the last word of each line prints. The code below shows how I'm adding each word to the list:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    token = strtok(line, delim);

    while (token != NULL) {
        if (search(head, token)) {
            node->count += 1; 
        } else {
            node->string = strdup(token);
            node->count = 1;
            node->next =NULL;
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    if (head == NULL) {
        current = head = node;
    } else {
        current = current->next = node;
    }
}
```

line initialization is: char *line[128]; search() returns true if the word is already in list and false otherwise, thus count is incremented if the word is present.
   and here is where I print:

```
for (current = head; current ; current = current->next) {
     current->string = strtok(current->string, "\n");
     printf("%-10s | %2d\n", current->string, current->count);
 }
```

For example, when using the text:

```
    mary had a little lamb
    its fleece was white as snow
    and every where that mary went
    the lamb was sure to go
```

The only words that get printed are lamb, snow, went, go

Comment: Maybe `current->string = strtok(current->string,"\n");` needs a strdup(), too.

Comment: You have some logical errors here. `search` returns what? A found node or NULL? When it finds a the word, why are you incrementing `count` on `node` instead of the count on the found node. Also, nowhere do I see you adding to the list.

Comment: @wildplasser tried that, but still does the same thing. I think it has something to do with my first while loop and how I'm adding elements to the list

Comment: And you are leaking memory and/or overwriting words. I would recommend rethinking your logic flow.

Comment: @MFisherKDX forgot to include what the search function does -- it returns true if the word is already in the list. i see my logic flaw with incrementing count on the wrong node but where am I overwriting words?

Comment: The second unique token on a single line overwrites your `node->string` in your else case. I would rewrite as follows. 1) Change `search` to return a node if found or NULL if not found. 2) If search returns a non-null value `n`, increment `n->count`. Else `malloc` a new node, add to the beginning, and update your head pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the word is already in the list. If it is in the list then there is no point to add it a second time. The `search` function should be returning `LIST*` which you can use to increment its value.

Also simplify the linked list as follows:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) 
{
    for (char *token = strtok(line, delim); token; token = strtok(NULL, delim))
    {
        int found = 0;
        for(LIST* n = head; n; n = n->next)
            if(strcmp(n->string, token) == 0)
            {
                n->count++;
                found = 1;
            }
        if(found) continue;

        LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
        node->next = NULL;
        node->count = 1;
        node->string = strdup(token);
        if(head)
            node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
}

for(LIST* n = head; n; n = n->next)
    printf("%s, %d\n", n->string, n->count);
```